# Need to Get data of ID ( received in Array ) from database

Tags: laravel

Good Morning. I am trying to get the data for each BuffaloID which i get in array. From that ID i am trying to get milk record for each buffaloID. But 2nd query give the data for first id only. How can i get the data for each id.

Query

```
     $buffalidforavgmilk     =   Buffalomilkrecord::groupBy('buffaloID')->get('buffaloID') 
     ->pluck('buffaloID')->toArray();

     array:4 [▼
             0 => "Buffalo-01"
             1 => "Buffalo-02"
             2 => "Buffalo-03"
             3 => "Buffalo-04"
             ]
```

When i try below query i received data only for first id

```
        $avgbuffalomilk = Buffalomilkrecord::where('buffaloID',$buffalidforavgmilk)-> 
        pluck('totalmilk')->toArray();

        array:5 [▼
                 0 => "9.00"
                 1 => "13.00"
                 2 => "12.00"
                 3 => "13.00"
                 4 => "12.00"
                 ]
```

I hope i describe my problem and where did i make mistake to get data for all ID
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

use `whereIn`

```
$buffalidforavgmilk = ['1','2','3'];
 
$avgbuffalomilk = Buffalomilkrecord::whereIn('buffaloID',$buffalidforavgmilk)->pluck('totalmilk')->toArray();
```